# How can I provide the first-error and next-error initial positions as region selection in order to save to the kill-ring?

Tags: region, compile-mode, script

I am running a make command. I'd like to capture the first error and output it to a file.

How can I select as a region from the beginning of `first-error` position to the position right before the `next-error` automatically such that it can be passed as an input to the `write-region` command to write it to a known file?

I am using the following function as a starting point, but I don't know how to select the region based on errors in the make output.

```
(defun copybuffer()
  "function takes current region, and writes it to specified file"
  (interactive)
  (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (write-region (region-beginning) (region-end) "~/copybuffer.txt"))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What's the question? A guess is that it's "How do I write a script to select...". If so, that's too broad a question for this site. Questions here should be specific, soliciting specific answers. Try narrowing to a particular thing you've tried and not succeeded to do, and ask about that. Or if you want to pose such a general advice-soliciting question, consider a discussion forum such as Reddit.

Comment: reddit is hardly a good discussion forum. I will try to distill the question further as I try more stuff. But I guess the first thing that would help me is the first question I asked in the post which is "How would one provide the first-error initial position and next-error initial position as an input to save to the ring buffer?"

Comment: Suggestion: Try that more straightforward how-to-provide-...positions question as your question, either by editing this one or by deleting this one and posting a new one.

Comment: I've updated the question per your suggestion.

Comment: I updated your question to just what was suggested. However, what do you mean by *"save to the ring buffer"*? What's the ring buffer? Which ring? Is your question really just how to get the initial limits of `first-error` and `next-error`? Not clear to me, at least.

Comment: maybe it sounds simple to you and that is why its confusing. I'd like to capture the first error within a make output and save it to the file. If its really that simple, then what is it? Unfortunately, I admit I only started using emacs this past weekend so hopefully the initial question was not confusing.  As I understand it, the kill ring is where regions go and it has the added bonus of where one can cycle through it - I thought this was a default behavior and was only referring it to for that reason (but isn't the end goal; the output to file is end goal). Perhaps my terminology is off??

Comment: I wasn't saying that the question is trivial. I tried to get you to narrow the question to a specific one. I edited it to what I thought you were saying was the specific question you wanted to ask. That doesn't involve using `make` etc., I believe.

Comment: But parts of your specific question are still unclear (to me): The kill ring it a ring of strings that were typically the content of the region at one time. There's no kill-ring buffer.
Now, I'm guessing (still mostly blindly) that you're really asking how to add the text pointed to by `first-error` and `next-error` to the `kill-ring`. Is that it? But those commands don't specify any text. They invoke a buffer-dependent function (the value of var `next-error-function`), which moves to the start position of that error in the error-listing buffer.

Comment: Perhaps someone else can translate your question. Or perhaps try reformulating it.

Comment: We are probably using the comment section too much like a discussion forum. Please try to answer the question best you can so we can move on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110325/discussion-between-leanman-and-drew).